# Can i not use rufus to install?

Tags: rufus

So i am trying to install Ubuntu Server 22.04.1 on my other computer, I use rufus to installm I get the option to try or install Ubuntu server, and then I do all the setup. It asks me to remove my USB then enter. But then it just says no operating system found, help?

Comment: Probably the problem is with your installation setup and not Rufus. Which is the partition scheme that you have defined? Boot, ESP, home and so on.

Comment: @raulquijadaferrero I use the default Rufus settings, havent changed anything. Currently using MBR for Partition scheme. FAT32 for file system